# Compiling php to visualize in svg-images in browser

Tags: php, compiler-construction, svg

I am writting a simple code (with some functions and simple equations) in php that creates some draws in svg format, but I am new in this language and I don't find a way of compiling the code to visualize it.
I found a site http://writecodeonline.com/php/ where I can copile part of the code and visualize some of the draws, but the numbers of lines limited (I think that is the line numbers). 
Do you know where I can compile the code and see the result in the browser? 
I've already opened svg images directly in the browser, but the file .svg where created in Matlab.

This php one, I'm doing in Noteped++.
I'd like to do something that could compile the php thing.

ideas?

here is an example of the code:

```
<?php
 function frmformula_Ax(){

 return 460;

 }

 function frmformula_Ay(){

 return 67.5;

 }

 $Ax = frmformula_Ax;
 $Ay = frmformula_Ay;
 $Bx=70;
 $By=70;

 $svg = '<svg width="3000" height="3000"

 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

 <path id="line_1" stroke="black" d="M' .$Ax.' '.$Ay.'   L '.$Bx.' ' .$By.' " stroke-width="2"/>

 </svg>';

 echo $svg;
     ?>
```

many thanks,

bruno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is an interpreted language, not compiled.  To parse it, you need a php interpreter.  This is most commonly done by running a webserver, such as [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/).  You can either run the server yourself or pay for a hosting service.

[This](http://lifehacker.com/124212/geek-to-live--how-to-set-up-a-personal-home-web-server) is a decent overview of how to set up a server yourself, assuming you're on windows.

Comment: I did not understand how works this Apache thing, but I'll read the website's information when I have more time. 
I wanted something more like "drop your code here and it will be interpretated". But thanks any way, this will be a start.

And also thanks for the link where teaches how set up a server on my own, this is another thing that I'll need to do soon, so it will be really helpfull.
thanks a lot, @Avery